Issue Adding User in Docker with Eclipse Temurin 17-jre Image
I am facing an issue when adding a user to a Docker container based on the Eclipse Temurin 17-jre image. The command I am using in my Dockerfile is:
RUN adduser --disabled-login -u 1000 spring-boot

However, when I build the image, I get the following error:

Could not build image: The command '/bin/sh -c adduser --disabled-login -u 1000 spring-boot' returned a non-zero code: 127

This command has been working for a long time, but the issue started this morning. I noticed that the latest tag for the 17-jre image was pushed two hours ago, which might be related to this issue.
Is there a different command or package that I need to install before adding a user to this base image? Any help would be appreciated!

There's this issue open on it on Github. It seems to be caused by moving from one version of Ubuntu to another in the base image used.

I'm facing the same issue since yesterday. It appears they changed the base image linked from 17-jre and 21-jre to the "noble" variant instead of the "jammy" variant (https://github.com/docker-library/docs/commit/0cbc4535db4fa332e8e4c9aee3220bc8e7223f78). A solution is to use the specific "17-jre-jammy" variant that still has the adduser and addgroup commands.

Since yesterday, the 17-jre, 21-jre, 17-jdk, 21-jdk... images point to the noble variant instead of the jammy variant. It seems the adduser and the addgroup commands don't exist in Ubuntu noble (replaced by useradd and groupadd).
If you don't want to change your scripts in your Dockerfile, you can change your FROM to use the more specific 17-jre-jammy instead of 17-jre.

adduser command is not present by default in eclipse-temurin:17-jre but useradd is.
Based on your specifications you can create the spring-boot user like so useradd --uid 1000 --no-create-home --shell /usr/sbin/nologin spring-boot. But beware of the user id 1000 since it is not unique and linked to the ubuntu user.

Is this a recent change in eclipse-temurin:17-jre? It was working fine until yesterday.

Not impossible, but I have not enough background to say. What is certain is that adduser does not exist on the current latest image.

We're facing the same issue in eclipse-temurin:21-jdk
It worked just fine since this morning. The command we were using is:
useradd <our user> --uid 1000 --disabled-password --no-create-home --gecos ''
I just installed adduser via apt-get and have a running right now. It is somewhat of a temporary workaround, does anyone have a clue what happened to the base image? Is this a hickup, or was there a plan to remove adduser command from the image?

User ID 1000 is used by the user ubuntu
docker run eclipse-temurin:17-jre cat /etc/passwd

Will show you that fact.
The way I used it before (adapting to your use csae) was to do
RUN echo spring-boot:x:1001:1001:Spring Boot:/nonexistent:/usr/sbin/nologin >> /etc/passwd


I had a problem with RUN addgroupa appuser.
I just changed command to RUN groupadd appuser.
I think they changed base image to newer ubuntu from 2024.
